# How to get ml-auto to work inside a parent with space-x-n applied?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin, tailwind-css

In Tailwind CSS, `ml-auto` (which is the equivalent of `margin-left: auto`) doesn't work if the element is inside of a parent with `space-x-n`. Is there any way to get it to work?  Here's an example:

```html
<div class="flex space-x-6">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
  <!-- Should be pushed to the right but isn't -->
  <button class="ml-auto">D</button>
</div>
```

I also tried applying `mx-0` before `ml-auto` but it still did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using JIT mode then you can important the rule of `ml-auto` on the button so `!ml-auto`. The way space-x works is with the lobotomized owl selector `* + *` which has a higher CSS specificity than any other Tailwind class. To override this rule you will need a higher specificity, Tailwind being utility first doesn't really allow modification of specificity aside from the important rule.

You could replace space-x with gap, there's only a few browsers holding out on support and they will give in eventually, at least one of them by way of death. https://caniuse.com/?search=gap